# Access inner class private vars from outer class

Tags: java, inner-classes, outer-classes

I am trying to access private val inside an inner class, from the outer class without creating an instance of the inner class.

Is this even possible to access `private inner class` values from `the outer class` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it is an instance variable, then you need ... an instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the field is `static`, you already can access it from the outer class even if it's `private`. You don't need an instance of either the inner or the outer class:

```
public class Clazz {
    class Inner {
        private static final int N = 10;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Inner.N);
    }
}
```

If the inner class field is not `static`, it does not *exist* without an instance of the inner class. You can't access something that doesn't exist.

Comment: [code]          System.out.println("Details for computer"+this.serial_number+"  "+new Video_Card (serial_number*100)) [/code]




i've tried this but for some reason its prints out the below :

Details for computer400 il.ac.shenkar.rec.Computer$Video_Card@67b56bda
Details for computer400 il.ac.shenkar.rec.Computer$Video_Card@37bbea67

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is the following. Inner class is just a regular class that has "magic" reference to *instance* of its outer class that can be accessible via `OuterClass.this`. Creating of instance of outer class does not create instance of inner class automatically. This means that you cannot by definition access members of inner class from outer class without creating instance of inner class unless inner class itself and its members are `static`.

Indeed you can create one instance of outer class and 10 instances of corresponding inner class. How can you access member of inner class without creating its instance?

BTW the general advice: avoid creating inner classes unless you really  need them.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the advice "avoid creating inner classes unless you really need them"?